# Probability distribution for product of dice rolls

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Say I'm rolling an $m$-sided die and an $n$-sided die once.

The probability distribution of all possible *sums* of the two dice rolls can be determined by normalizing the coefficients the product of $f_m(x) = x + \dots + x^m$ and $f_n(x) = x + \dots + x^n$. Is there an analogous way to determine the probability distribution of the *products* of the two dice rolls via operations on polynomials? Is there maybe even a more general way to do this for arbitrary functions? Ideally something that can actually be computed without having to solve an integral or similar.

Comment: Put $X$ - number on the first dice and $Y$ - number of the second dice. Then distribution of $XY$ we may get from distribution of $\ln(XY) = \ln X + \ln Y$ which is the sum of independent r.v.